# C copy static array into a structure

Tags: c, pointers, deep-copy

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
typedef struct object {
  entry **entries;
} object;

typedef struct entry {
  int value;
} entry;
```

Somewhere in my code i have a static array of entries(initialized with some random data);

```
entry entries[][] = {... (doesn't matter)...};
```

How can i copy these entries into an object?
I need something like this:

```
object obj;
obj.entries = entries;
```

Edit: I do not want to copy every element in a 'for' loop.

After suggestions:

Ok. I have:

```
entry entries[initial_height][initial_width];
....initialize entries...
object obj;
int i;
obj.entries = (entry**) malloc(initial_height * sizeof(entry*));

for (i = 0 ; i < initial_height; i++) {
    obj.entries[i] = (entry*) malloc(initial_width * sizeof(entry));
}

memcpy(obj.entries, entries, sizeof(entry) * initial_height * initial_width);

printf("%d\n", entries[0][0].value);
printf("%d\n", obj.entries[0][0].value);
```

And i'm getting a segmentation fault(the first print works). What am i still doing wrong?

Comment: try memcpy to copy if you know the size of element to copy

Comment: These have different types! A pointer is not an array!

Comment: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) You have a pointer to pointer, not a 2D array in your `struct`. This is not the same as a 2D array! 3) You invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: I know that it is not the same as a 2D array. I want to know how to make it point to that 2D array(or another array with same values)

Comment: Nothing like `obj.entries = entries` is possible.  `obj.entries` is a pointer which points to other pointers. But there are no pointers to point to, you've declared an array (which is not a pointer).

Comment: in the edited version, the `memcpy` is hopeless. You just allocated several small memory blocks, all in different locations. How do you expect to use a single memcpy to write them all at once. In C it's important to have a clear mental image of where your memory allocations are.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you describe which of the dimensions of the array are known at compile-time

Comment: Yes you are right, I allocated memory blocks because they suggested to use a memcpy if they have the same size. And from what i know, the memory is continuous for a 2d static array. So can i somehow make my pointer point to the address of the 2d static array?

Comment: The dimensions are read from a file.

Comment: You can't have the struct point to the array either, if both dimensions are read from a file.  Instead you can have the struct contain two integers for the dimensions, and a `void *`  ;and then the code that needs to use the array can cast the `void *` to pointer to array of the right dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with `memcpy`. The basic idea in `memcpy` is that it starts from the 2 pointers specified in the parameters of `memcpy` and copies the number of bytes specified by you.

In your case you follow 2 steps::

1) You declare an array of pointers of `entry`.

2) You declare arrays of `entry` and save the pointer returned by `malloc` into the array of pointers declared in (1).

You should also take into consideration that your every array declared in step (2) could be declared anywhere in the memory not necessarily contiguously.

So, when you call `memcpy(obj.entries[i], entries[i], sizeof(entry) * initial_width);` you start copying bytes of `entries` to the array of pointers `obj.entries[i]` which is only of size `initial_height * sizeof(entry*)`, so anything you copied beyond this limit, is corrupting the memory, which is the reason you get a segmentation fault. (Since you also over-write the bytes storing the location of dynamically declared arrays of `entry`)

A possible approach to do it would be as follows ::

```
for(int i = 0; i < initial_height; i++) {
    memcpy(obj.enteries[i], entries[i], sizeof(entry) * initial_width);
}
```

You will anyway have to use 1 `for` loop if you want to create your 2D array dynamically. In case you don't want this either, you will have to declare a static array!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to allocate and copy at the same place:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < initial_height; i++) {
    obj.entries[i] = (entry*) malloc(initial_width * sizeof(entry));
    memcpy(obj.entries[i], entries[i], sizeof(entry) * initial_width);
}
```